# Is WiFi Calling possible over reverse tethering?

Tags: wi-fi

For internet access on my smartphone I use reverse tethering via USB from my PC while having it in flight mode. Everything works great (WhatsApp, Chrome, etc.) except calls, of course.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use "WiFi" calls without WiFi but with internet over reverse tethering via USB while the smartphone is in flight mode?

Comment: Why don't you try it with the setup that you have? You could get your answer very quickly.

Comment: Based on my understanding, isn't the technology called VoIP (Voice-over-IP)? So it shouldn't be necessarily using Wi-Fi, but anything that connects to the internet should work?

Comment: ... and you just need to make sure that your router (and PC or whatever the hosts in between) isn't blocking ports used for VoIP calls.

Comment: Unfortunately, my current smartphone does not meet the necessary requirements (Android 7+), since it runs on Android 6 and there are no more updates probably because it is a Huawai. And before I buy a new one I would like to make sure that it works

Comment: Also I am not sure whether it is possible to turn on "WiFi" calls in the flight mode?